# How to add a picklist value to Type__c of a Contact in a unit test?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am trying to test a method in a services class in my org. Within my TestDataUtility class I have a `List<Contact> createContact` however, there is no `Type` field in this test data. I am not sure if it is even possible to add `Type__c` to a contact (since it is a standard object.)

I do know that `Type` field exists within the actual standard object and it is a picklist.

Here is how I am editing the object within my test:

```
static testMethod void test_setAlumniRelationship (){
        List<Account> accountForContactServ =
                TestDataUtility.createTestAccount(1, 'account name', true);
        List<Contact> createContact=
                TestDataUtility.createContacts(1,accountForContactServ[0].Id, true);
                for(Contact indvContact : createContact){
                    createContact.add(indvContact.Type__c);
                    createContact.Type = 'Alumni';
                    break;

                }
```

The error i get is: `Incompatible element type String for collection of SOBJECT:Contact`

Thank you for all your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for you response, However what really was wrong is that I didnt need that for loop, since i just want to update one contact I simply had to do the following

```
createContact[0].Type__c = 'Alumni';
```

Although my test data does not have this field Type__c. I still do not need to create it because it is a standard object it will automatically have this field.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your createContact is a List, so there is no type element on the list.

```
createContact.add(indvContact.Type__c);
createContact.Type = 'Alumni';
```

You are trying to add the string Type_*c from each contact to a list that is expecting you to add a contact.
Could you add all of your test class?  It appears you are trying to actually update the test contact record with a type*_c = 'Alumni' to test your code.
If so, it would be something like this:

```
static testMethod void test_setAlumniRelationship (){
        List<Account> accountForContactServ =
                TestDataUtility.createTestAccount(1, 'account name', true);
        List<Contact> updateContact = new List<Contact>();
        List<Contact> createContact=
                TestDataUtility.createContacts(1,accountForContactServ[0].Id, true);
                for(Contact indvContact : createContact){
                   indvContact.Type = 'Alumni';
                   updateContact.add(indvContact);
                }
         update updateContact;//update list of new contacts with Alumni
 }
```

If your testdatautility.createContacts doesn't save the record, you can actually loop through directly, then insert the createContacts list.

Answer (score 0):

I think you doing a small mistake which is

```
            for(Contact indvContact : **createContact**){
                **createContact**.add(indvContact.Type__c);
                *createContact*.Type = 'Alumni';
                break;
            }
```

1) In for loop your are adding a instance of contact in the list on which you are Traversing. So it is wrong.
2) before **break;** line you are doing some silly mistake use  indvContact.type  instead createContact.Type